# Call sql functions in node.js modules using module.exports

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I have my main routes file called main.js, in which I want to call sql functions from a module called database.js Within the database.js file I am able to retrieve the data, however when passing to main.js it keep saying that data is undefined.

main.js

```
const database = require('./modules/database')

app.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = database.getAll()
        console.log(data)
        res.render('home', {stock: data})
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err.message)
        res.render('empty')
    }
})
```

database.js

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()

const db = new sqlite3.Database('./stockInventory.db', (err) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err.message)
    console.log('Connected to the "stockInventory.db" SQlite database.')
})

module.exports.getAll = () => {
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM stock;'
    console.log(sql)
    db.all(sql, (err, data) => {
        if(err) console.error(err.message)
        //console.log(data)
        return data
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need callback function, Try this

```
const database = require('./modules/database')

app.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    try {
         database.getAll(function(data) {
         console.log(data)
         res.render('home', {stock: data})
    })

        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err.message)
            res.render('empty')
        }
    })

module.exports.getAll = (callback) => {
    const sql = 'SELECT * FROM stock;'
    console.log(sql)
    db.all(sql, (err, data) => {
        if(err) console.error(err.message)
        //console.log(data)
        callback(data);
    })
}
```

Comment: After adding this my localhost doesn't load to display the website.

Comment: Once the loading is done i get an error in my localhost saying 'localhost didn’t send any data.'

Comment: @CharlesKausihan, in console log you get this error

Comment: in console log I get:

app listening on port 8080
Connected to the "stockInventory.db" SQlite database.
SELECT * FROM stock;

Comment: @CharlesKausihan, edit his module.exports.getAll = (data) => { plz

Comment: @CharlesKausihan, in database.js

Comment: Same issue, data is being loaded in database.js (I can see that in terminal), however localhost is not loading.

Comment: @CharlesKausihan, add         return callback(data) in database.js

Comment: I get an error:

                    throw err;
                    ^

ReferenceError: callback is not defined

Comment: @CharlesKausihan, not forget to accept my answer ;)

Comment: Works like a charm... thank you so much for you help... I have accepted your answer.